# Redeclaring a non-static inline function as extern

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is it legal C to redeclare an inline function as `extern` in an inner scope?

Would the code below be legal C with or without `MACRO` being truthy?

```
#if MACRO
    enum { have_macro = 1 };
    inline int foo(void){ return 43; }
#else
    enum { have_macro = 0 };
#endif
int main()
{
    if(have_macro){
        extern int foo(void);
        return foo();
    }else
        return 0;
}
extern int foo(void); //maybe instantiate
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the meaning of the comment "maybe instantiate;" ?

Comment: @M.M. If MACRO is truthy, the inline definition will be provided, and `extern int foo(void);` will instantiate it; otherwise, it will be just a plain old extern declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preliminary note for non-language-lawyers: the term *external definition* in C is not to be confused with `extern` or *external linkage*. It means, roughly, "any definition that appears at file scope and is not an inline definition".  For example, a static function definition would be an external definition. See section 6.9 of the C17 standard for more detailed coverage.

Also note that the term *inline definition* has its own quirks; a function definition with `inline` keyword may be either an *inline defintion* or an *external definition* depending on other things which I will cover below.

---

For the following code (which results from `MACRO` being defined):

```
inline int foo(void){ return 43; }
int main()
{
    if(1){
        extern int foo(void);
        return foo();
    }else
        return 0;
}
extern int foo(void);
```

The first line provides an *external definition* for `foo`, and not an inline definition:

The rule is that if there is a definition of a function with external linkage that has the `inline` keyword, **and** a file-scope declaration of that function without the `inline` keyword, then the function definition is an external definition. See C17 6.7.4/10 for almost this exact example.   The block-scope declaration makes no difference.

This code is OK so far, however it would be undefined behaviour if another translation unit also provided an external definition for `foo`.

---

For the version without MACRO:

```
int main()
{
    if(0){
        extern int foo(void);
        return foo();
    }else
        return 0;
}
extern int foo(void);
```

This code is also fine so far, but it would be undefined behaviour if there were not exactly one definition of the `foo` function in the program somewhere. (C17 6.9/5)  Hiding the code behind `if(0)` does not get away from the one definition rule.

Comment: Thanks. Second part at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042003/using-extern-to-refer-to-the-instantiation-of-a-non-static-inline-function .

Comment: "The first line provides an external definition for foo, and not an inline definition." - [That would seem inaccurate](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9).

Comment: @StoryTeller My paragraph after the one you quoted explains the rule and gives a reference. I'm not sure what you intended to point out with your link, could you elaborate?

Comment: The order threw me off, apologies. It seemed like an unqualified assertion.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it legal C to redeclare an inline function as extern in an inner scope?

Yes, but if you have it also defined without inline in other translation unit, it's ambigious which one is used.

> On a similar topic, can I link with an instantiated non-static inline by declaring it extern in another file?

No, inline functions are only visible to compilation unit they are declared and defined in.

> #### 6.7.4 Function specifiers
>
> 7. Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. **For a function with external linkage,
>      the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it
>      shall also be defined in the same translation unit.** If all of the file scope declarations for a function in
>      a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern , then the definition in that
>      translation unit is an inline definition. **An inline definition does not provide an external definition
>      for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline
>      definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement
>      any call to the function in the same translation unit.** It is unspecified whether a call to the function
>      uses the inline definition or the external definition.

Comment: You are totally wrong, `inline` non-static function has external linkage.

Comment: @ZangMingJie - I'm afraid you are wrong. C is different than C++ in that regard. And you can't very well say the C standard(quoted here) is wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller it is correct that a function definition without `static` defines a function with external linkage, if the identifier has not been declared already. Whether or not the definition has the `inline` keyword.

Comment: @M.M - That does not coincide with *"An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function"*. You need an additional external definition for the name to have linkage.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you are misunderstanding the term *external definition*  (it is not related to `extern` or having external linkage). Note - C17 6.2.2/5 covers that non-static function names have external linkage.

Comment: @M.M - Do I? Yes, [I needed a refresher](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9). But now that puts the accuracy of your own answer under debate. You seem to be interchanging "external definition" with "external linkage" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` does nothing at language grammar level, it doesn't change function signature, linkage or visibility.

`extern` is a declaration, you must declare the function with the same signature as definition. And `inline` doesn't affect function signature and visibility only `static` does.

As long as you doesn't violate [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) in the same translation unit, it is fine. If multiple units exports same weak definition, random one be chosen at link or load time.

Comment: I'm going to give this my +1 until someone explains what's wrong with this answer, because, nitpicks aside, this lines up with my understanding - that `static` actually does something substantially meaningful at the language level, while `inline` only does something if the compiler is unable or not allowed to optimize the code as well as modern compilers can.