# Using extern to refer to the instantiation of a non-static inline function

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is it possible to link with an instantiated non-static inline function by declaring it `extern` in another file?:

inline.c:

```
inline int foo(void) { return 42; }
extern inline int foo(void);
```

main.c:

```
extern int foo(void);
int main(){ return foo(); }
```

Empirically `$CC main.c inline.c` (where CC is `gcc`, `clang` or `tcc`) works. Is it a conforming C example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question here is about the behaviour of `extern inline int foo(void);` in the same translation unit as the apparent inline definition.

The text from C17 6.7.4/7 is:

> If all of the file scope declarations for a function in
>   a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern` , then the definition in that translation unit is an *inline definition*.

The "If all..." clause does not hold for `inline.c`, since the second line declares the identifier with `extern`.  So the first line is actually an *external definition*, not an inline definition.

Then, using `extern int foo(void);` in the other translation unit is fine. `foo` is a function with external linkage which has an external definition.  There is no rule precluding this.

---

It would also be fine if `inline.c` only contained the first line, which would be an *inline definition*, and `extern inline int foo(void);` appeared in a third translation unit.  `foo` is still a function with external linkage and having an external definition.

Any inline definition is only relevant in the same translation unit as the inline definition.